# Error Type 3 - Activity does exist

Tags: java, android

Toda vez que tento executar meu app no AVD ou no próprio celular para testar a seguinte mensagem aparece para mim:

```
Error while executing: 
  am start -n "com.example.vantajoso/com.example.vantajoso.MainActivity" 
    -a android.intent.action.MAIN
    -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER

Starting: Intent { 
  act=android.intent.action.MAIN
  cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
  cmp=com.example.vantajoso/.MainActivity }

Error type 3 Error: 
  Activity class {com.example.vantajoso/com.example.vantajoso.MainActivity} 
  does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

Abaixo segue como está o meu AndroidMaifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="com.example.vantajoso">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

  <application android:allowBackup="true" 
    android:icon="@mipmap/iconvantajosoweb_round" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/iconvantajosoweb_round" 
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>

    </activity>


  </application>
</manifest>
```

Meu MainActivity

```java
package com.example.vantajoso;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private WebView mWebView;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //remove o titulo
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    //codigo para o webview
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://meusite.com.br");
  }
}
```

Alguém tem ideia do que seja?

Comment: Me parece que esta linha `<action android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` deveria ser `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

Comment: @icaroMartins Tentei aqui mas acontece o mesmo erro.
Já não faço ideia do que fazer :X

Answer (score 2):

Em meu caso o erro surgiu de uma alteração na *configuração de execução* quando estava tentando rodar em modo release. Possivelmente devo ter colocado algo incorreto na configuração. Tentei as possibilidades dadas nesta questão, não foram acertivas, mas recomento utilizar antes de minha solução. Meu caso tive que deletar e refazer a *configuração de execução*.

Para isso:

- Encontre a *configuração de execução* - similar a imagem, normalmente com nome de **app**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou navegando via menu **Run**

- Selecione `Edit Configuration...` como a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou navegando via menu `Run > Edit Configuration...`

- Apague a configuração existente (salve os parâmetros personalizados caso existam) e recrie.

Isso resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Quando comparamos seu manifest com um de [exemplo do Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro#example), da para notar uma diferença nesta linha de seu manifest:

```xml
<action android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<!--  ^                                 ^  -->
```

no exemplo esta assim:

```xml
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<!--  ^ category                         ^  -->
```

Isso pode/poderia ser um dos problemas, como foi dito nos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/426576/error-type-3-activity-does-exist#comment827690_426576) que isso não resolveu, a próxima tentativa seria limpar o cache do projeto, como é explicado aqui nessa [resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24241687/2456894).

1. *Limpar Projeto*:  **Build** -> **Clear Project**
2. Deletar o diretório `Build`
3. Reiniciar o Android Studio
4. Remover o Aplicativo do Smartphone
5. *Compilar Projeto*: **Build** -> **Rebuild Project**
6. **Run**
7. *(opcional) Invalidar cache*: **File** -> **Invalidate Caches / Restart...**